pascal theorem in algebraic geometry
In my algebraic geometry class, I am studying intersection theory on $\mathbb{P}^2$. The teacher gave an example: Pascal's theorem.

He mentioned a more general theorem in algebraic geometry: let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be cubic curves, and let $\gamma$ be a conic. Denote the intersection points of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as $p_{1}, \dots, p_{9}$. Assume that $p_{1}, \dots, p_{6}$ are smooth points of $\alpha$ and are also intersection points of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$. Then $p_{7}, p_{8}, p_{9}$ are collinear. 
My question is, in the Pascal theorem of plane geometry, how can these line segments be regarded as cubic curves? 
According to the description in the theorem, it seems that we can consider $\alpha = \{AB, EF, CD\}$ and $\beta = \{AF, ED, CB\}$, but are these really cubic curves?

the union of 3 straight lines (not just segments) is a cubic curve

Why? Is there any related explanation or proof? Does the same conclusion hold for conic curves?@user8268

the union of 3 lines is given by the (cubic) equation $l_1l_2l_3=0$, where the $i$'th line is given by $l_i=0$
